# Route to specific tab using anchor in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to create a link which opens a tab from ng-bootstrap.

The tab has a specific id and I am creating the link as follows:

```
 [routerLink]="['/path/', i.name]" fragment="anchorid"
```

The url is created correctly but the tab is not opened. It always shows the first tab on the page.

I am using hash navigation with Angular 4.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you are using router outlet to view the next tab.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```